# .on is dependent on another .on event

Tags: javascript, events

I have this code :

```
$document.on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  $document.on('focusin', function (e) {
    console.log('bleh');
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is online when you receive the event : show.bs.dropdown then you activate the focuin event. I am doing this because I don't want a focusin event to be fired when it's not in the show.bs.dropdown context....This code works, but it multiply the event everytime I fire show.bs.dropdown...I need to leave focuin "on" as soon as the show.bs.dropdown so it can never be off.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Did you forget a framework tag?

Comment: That is JavaScript...

Comment: No it isn't. It looks like it might be jQuery but you haven't specified.

Comment: ah okay fair point, how do I change it